# Command button that changes the value of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jsf, event-handling, textarea, commandbutton

In order to answer this other question ([Use Froala Editor with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661077/use-froala-editor-with-jsf)), I need to pass the content of a div similar to this:

```
<div class="fr-view">
  Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

To the value of the following inputTextarea (#{newArticleController.body}) when the commandButton is clicked.

```
<h:form id="formId">
  <h:inputTextarea id="articleBody" value="#{newArticleController.body}" styleClass="articleTextarea"/>
  <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{newArticleController.newArticle}"/>
</h:form>
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
   <script>
     function updateBody() {
       var body = document.getElementById('formId:articleBody');
       var div = $('.fr-view');
       body.value = div.value;
     }
   </script>

   ...

   <h:form id="formId">
     <h:inputTextarea id="articleBody" value="#{newArticleController.body}" styleClass="articleTextarea"/>
     <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{newArticleController.newArticle}" onclick="updateBody();"/>
   </h:form>
```

I always receive null in the body variable. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: BalusC, the div.value has undefined, but I have noticed now that body.value has initially the value correctly but when I press the button the value that arrives to the #{newArticleController.body} variable is null

Comment: If I don't do body.value = div.value; I also get the null value even when body.value has a value, I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Sine your $('.fr-view') is a div `$('.fr-view')`will not work. To get the text or `innerHtml` of a div you need to use `$('fr-view').html()` or `$('fr-view').text()`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it without the onclick javascript code. I was putting pt:name="content" in the inputTextarea. When I removed it, it worked.